# Use c++ dll in wpf (c#) and entry point exception

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dllimport

I am trying to import dll c++ dll in c# but system shows exception

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named '0x00011091' in DLL 'D:\ project \ RunningProcessDll\Debug \RunningProcessDll .dll'.'

This is **dllmain.cpp** file

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dllmain.h"

UINT PID_GetProcessId() {

TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH];
DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
unsigned int i;
EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded);
cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++) {
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
        PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE, aProcesses[i]);
    if (NULL != hProcess)
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod),
            &cbNeeded))
        {
            GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        }
    }
    return aProcesses[i];

}

}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
}
return TRUE;
}
```

This is **dllmain.h** file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT PID_GetProcessId();
```

This is c# wpf application file

```
[DllImport(@"D:\\project\\RunningProcessDll\\Debug\\RunningProcessDll.dll",
        EntryPoint ="0x00011091", CallingConvention = 
CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern uint PID_GetProcessID();
    int a = size();
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
        {
            dg.Items.Add(new Process()
            {

                ID = PID_GetProcessID().ToString(),

            });
        }
```

I have gone through multiple sites but problem did not resolve.
I even checked entry point of function through dependency wrapper and then add it in dllImport but this exception still occur

Comment: Pretty unclear why you thought that EntryPoint value was a good idea.  It wasn't, delete it so the function can be found by its name.  If you still have trouble then verify the exported function names by running Dumpbin.exe /exports RunningProcessDll.dll.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, declare the exported function in the cpp as it declared in the header: with the `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` prefix

Comment: The error message could hardly be more clear. Now, I have a question for you. What do you think that the error message means?

Comment: Your code is looking for a string entry point called : "0x00011091".  Don't use just want to use the hex number?

Comment: I declared the function as u said in second comment, remove entry point value and enter the name of function instead of value but still shows that exception

Comment: 2    1 00011091 PID_GetProcessId = @ILT+140(_PID_GetProcessId) is the name of function that I found through Dumpbin.exe

Comment: Not much i understand why this error occur because i tried all ways that resolve this error but all in vain

Comment: The function is named PID_GetProcessId

Comment: Oh, i didn't catch that mistake. thanks for pointing out this....But the function return null value

Comment: Your question does not ask about that. It asks about the error reported. If the function returns zero the that's because, we'll, it returns zero. Read the code, use a debugger, and work out why.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is resolved.